# Best practices for securing return to previous page after login or back link url

Tags: php, security

I found many way for redirect to previous page after login and example :

1. `$_GET` - need to validate
2. `$_SESSION` - will override the value if using multiple tabs
3. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - it's sent by the browser to the server

On form we can use

```
<form action="/process/?return=/previous/page/?id=123" method="post" />
```

or using hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="$_GET or $_SESSION or $_SERVER" />
```

May I know what is the best practices to secure the return value?

Comment: All those methods can be spoofed. Do you have any reason to why you need this to be `secure`?

Comment: You can't use 

    <form action="http://domain.com/?return=/previous/page/?id=123" method="post" />

A request must be GET or POST, not both. This may work on a direct connection, but may break wen you put a proxy.

Comment: i think you want protect yourself from "form spoofing" ? if so read http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/6_Spoofed-Form-Submissions

Comment: you can add `return` param on all anchors and buttons with javascript onclick event. all depends on what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common practice (also on e-commerce sites in payment checkout) is to have a hidden input with the URL to redirect to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" />
```

It seems to be secure enough for most people...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are three solutions that come into my mind:

The best solution would be to create a whitelist containing all possible urls, but that is unmanagable in most cases. If you have the possibility you can auto-create the urls (maybe from database?).
Neverthless:

```
<?php
  $whitelist = array('url1', 'url2',...);

  $referer = $_POST['referer'];

  if(in_array($referer, $whitelist))
  {
     header('Location: '.$referer);  // redirect to target
  }
  else
  {
     header('Location: /');  // redirect to default page
  }
?>
```

The second solution that comes into my mind would be to check the url using regular expressions (depends from where your user can come from).

The third solution seems to use a secret key for generating a token, that prevents the user from form-tampering:

```
<?php
    $referer = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES); // request-url or get value whatever you like
    $secret = 'sfhuwefwejori234'; // key of your choice
    $token = sha1($secret.$referer); 
?>

<form action=....>
  <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<?php echo $referer; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="refToken" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
...
```

On the target page, before redirecting the user, recreate the token with the passed value and check if it is correct:

```
<?php
  $referer = $_POST['referer'];
  $token = $_POST['refToken'];
  $secret = 'sfhuwefwejori234';  // SAME key as above, do never include this into a form, user cannot know this key

  $originalToken = sha1($secret.$referer);

  if($originalToken == $token)
  {
     header('Location: '.$referer); // redirect user
  }
  else
  {
     header('Location: /'); // Redirect to default page
  }
?>
```

This will protect you from form tampering and cross-site-scripting.

Cheers!

Answer (score -4):

I don't understand what security you are talking about.

For the most modern web-applications you don't have to return anywhere as you just keep with the same URL throughout the whole process.